# How to prevent Popup Error in Browser when forwarding to User to external Page with Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

Hi i am forwarding users from a Vaadin 14 App to PayPal so they can login and pay. But all browsers are supressing it and showing a little Message "popup supressed, click to open popup"

Most of the users are not recogniczing this message and leave withput paying.

How can i change the behavior?

Currently this code row is responsible for forwarding:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().open("https://xxxx", "_blank");
```

BrowserWindowOpener has been removed from vaadin 14 so i cant use this.

Comment: Use an Anchor / Link that people have to click.

Comment: then a button would also work if the user "activly" hit the button/anchor?

Comment: It depends on the browser. You best bet is a real anchor.